# OLEDB Connection Error To SQL Server 2016 / Windows Server 2012R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, sql-server-2016, oledbconnection

We recently installed a SQL Server 2016 Standard instance on a Windows Server 2012R2. When we are trying to create an OLEDB connection we receive the following error

[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (SECDoClientHandshake()).]SSL Security error

[image]

I searched the internet and non of the solutions worked for us.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/3135244/tls-1.2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server

Comment: [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (SECDoClientHandshake()).]SSL Security error

Comment: new info
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlnativeclient/2017/10/06/announcing-the-new-release-of-ole-db-driver-for-sql-server/comment-page-1/#comment-11495

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server support TLS 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46011694/does-microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-support-tls-1-2)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

TLS1.2 does not support OLEDB connections

Comment: NO LONGER VALID ANSWER

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft has released new OleDb driver which supports TLS 1.2.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlnativeclient/2018/03/30/released-microsoft-ole-db-driver-for-sql-server/