# SQL OLEDB fails with TLS 1.2

Tags: sql-server, tls1.2

I know this is a very generic question, and already answered in some forums but I am having issue. I am having SQL Server 2012 and 2015 (which would be migrated to 2018). The SQL OLEDB connection with SqlClient works well with TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.0. But when we use TLS 1.2, it fails to connect.

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46011694/does-microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-support-tls-1-2) and this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlnativeclient/2017/10/06/announcing-the-new-release-of-ole-db-driver-for-sql-server/), explaining the same, but any more changes I need to make in my application, regarding Provider etc.

Thanks In Advance!!!..

Answer (score 1):

You should Use "SQLNCLI11" driver to connect to the database or you can install new OLEDB provider from here :
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56730
and set provider to "MSOLEDBSQL"