# SQL Server Excel vba odbc connection string after tls 1.2 server patch without installing driver

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, tls1.2

We have two SQL Server 2012 machines hosting the databases for multiple Excel vba programs.

A recent patch to one of these servers (the development server) applied upgraded the server to tls 1.2 from tls 1.0.

This means we are no longer able to communicate with the SQL Server using the deprecated oledb connection type.

My only success so far in retrieving data has come from manually installing the Microsoft odbc driver on the clients machine (windows 7 and windows 10). Once installed, the connection on tls 1.2 works. I would prefer to not have to install this driver on all existing and new client machines.

My question really is.. is there a connection string that will allow a connection from Excel vba to SQL Server via odbc where I do not have to install the driver on each clients machine.. I have tested numerous connection strings from `connectionstrings.com` but all seem to now be blocked by the server. If I make a connection from Excel to the data via a data link within Excel, I am able to retrieve data via some sort of odbc connection that Excel itself creates. I'm perplexed that there is no driver I can use for this odbc connection automatically on these machines. Or am I missing something in the connection string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server support TLS 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46011694/does-microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-support-tls-1-2)?

Comment: Modern SQL Server drivers are separate installs nowadays. The ones that ship windows are included only for backwards compatibility. Rather than ODBC, consider using the current OLEDB provider (MSOLEDBSQL) referenced in the answer link @Larnu mentioned.