# Using the SQLOLEDB driver (not MSOLESQLDB)

Tags: sql-server, vb6, sqloledb

A recent update on our database server to disable TLS1.0 and 1.1 has forced me down the route of investigating which provider I can use to connect a legacy VB app to a SQL Server 2016 database.

I understand the SQLOLEDB driver isn't being maintained anymore and the recommendation is to use MSOLEDBSQL. However updating connection strings to use MSOLEDBSQL isn't really going to be viable for me.

For most users the client app is running on Windows 10 enterprise build which actually contains an updated version of SQLOLEDB which works with TL1.2; so no problems here.

But, some of users are running the client app on Windows server 2016 which contains an older version of SQLOLEDB (sqloledb.dll v10.0.14393.6167) which appears doesn't support TLS1.2

Question is: Does anyone where I can actually install the latest version of SQLOLEDB from? Searching on Microsoft always diverts to providing MSOLEDBSQL for download (and not SQLOLEDB)! Could we simply copy the newer sqloledb.dll to the affected servers?

Many thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is sqloledb actually using MSOLEDBSQL on Windows Server 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67943468/is-sqloledb-actually-using-msoledbsql-on-windows-server-2019)

Comment: Unfortunately not. One of comments does suggest sticking with SQLOLEBD but its still unclear to me how to get the updated version of SQLOLEDB onto Windows Server 2016?

Comment: Note that WDAC component versions, including the legacy SQLOLEDB provider, are part of the operating system. You won't be able to install the newer SQLOLEDB version with TLS 1.2 support on a down-level OS like Windows Server 2016. [You need Windows Server 2019 or later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46011694/does-microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-support-tls-1-2/46012912#46012912).

Comment: Can't you undisable tls1.0 via registry? Or maybe it's time to upgrade... Changing connection strings to use the latest msoledb drivers should be the best way though? Or is it hardcoded in the vb app? perhaps good time to upgrade that as well

Comment: Thanks for the above comments. Great to get the confirmation that installing the newer SQLOLEDB version won't be an option for Server 2016. That's the price of the puzzle that I wasn't comprehending!