# CRUD operation not work with ADODB and SQL server using MSOLEDBSQL19 Provider and "strict" option (TLS1.3)

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic, oledb, tls1.3

In classic ASP pages, I am trying to connect SQL server 2k22 using the ADODB connection and MSOLEDBSQL19 driver(provider).
On the SQL Server Side, I enabled the Force encryption=Yes and client-side(ASP pages) in connection string added **Use Encryption for data=optional** Key. Also, proper certificates are applied on the SQL server as well as on the client side.
In this situation Connection is established between ADDOB and SQL server using **TLS 1.2** (TDS 7) protocol. and all types of query (CRUD) working properly.

```
<%
dim sDept
sDept="Batting"
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

conn.mode=3
conn.Open "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL19;Use Encryption for data=Optional;Password=Password@123;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=Testdb;Data Source=sql2k22.test.com;Application Name=Test App"
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
rs.Open "Select * from Players where dept = '" & sDept & "'" , conn,2,3,1
rs("Name")="Rohit"
rs.update

do until rs.EOF
    for each x in rs.Fields
       Response.Write(x.name)
       Response.Write(" = ")
       Response.Write(x.value & "<br>")
    next
    Response.Write("<br>")
    rs.MoveNext
loop

rs.close
conn.close
%>
```

Now I want to Use **TLS 1.3** Protocol for that purpose change the key value, Use Encryption for data=strict. after this change SQL connection was established using TLS 1.3 protocol and was able to fetch (SELECT query) records from SQL table.

```
conn.Open "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL19;Use Encryption for data=Strict;Password=Password@123;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=Testdb;Data Source=sql2k22.test.com;Application Name=Test App"
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
rs.Open "Select * from Players where dept = '" & sDept & "'" , conn
```

but when I Used the "Update query" it failed. and shows error

*ADODB.Recordset error '800a0cb3'
Current Recordset does not support updating. This may be a limitation of the provider, or of the selected locktype.*

and if we provided the lock type during recordset.open `rs.Open "Select * from Players where dept = '" & sDept & "'" , conn,2,3,1` then it failed with error

*Microsoft OLE DB Driver 19 for SQL Server error '80004005'
The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) protocol stream is incorrect. The stream ended unexpectedly.*

**Environment:**

1:SQL Server 2K22 (tried with SQL EXPRESS as well as SQL Developer).
2:MSOLEDBSQL driver:version 19.3.2.
3:client and server side: win2k22 server OS
4:classic ASP and ADODB connection.

I also tried with **Encrypt=strict** key in the connection string but the connection happened over TLS 1.2 protocol (TDS 7 pre-login).

I want to do CRUD operation over TLS 1.3 protocol using ASP-ADODB-MSOLEDBSQL19-SQL(2k22) on Win 2k22 server OS.

Comment: Are you using the correct driver? TLS 1.3 support was only added in 19.2.0 - See [Release notes for the Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/release-notes-for-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: It's a bit weird to see you being concerned about TLS security yet having [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/11683) in your code.

Comment: @GSerg I agree with you but this is sample app, actual code is different.In  real code I taking care of that

Comment: I've heard that excuse so many times, why should standards be ignored just because it's a sample app?

Comment: @user692942 Yes I am using the latest MSOLEDBSQL driver version 19.3.2

Comment: What version is the SQL Server Database? - [Is sqloledb actually using MSOLEDBSQL on Windows Server 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67944101) (TLS 1.3 support in `MSOLEDBSQL19` is SQL Server 2016+)

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM) - 16.0.1000.6 (X64)   Oct  8 2022 05:58:25   Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2022 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 20348: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Okay, but what version is the database not the server?

Comment: Also, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/networking/tds-8?view=sql-server-ver16) might be useful as it details exceptions to using TDS 8.0.

Comment: @user692942 what is meant by database version? how it check?

Comment: @MangeshAuti In the Database Properties look at the Compatibility Level. See [View or change the compatibility level of a database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/view-or-change-the-compatibility-level-of-a-database?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: compatibility_level  =160

Comment: It almost looks like a bug. But are you really using the classic classic asp as in .asp? Can you update using tls 1.2 with same code?

Comment: @MangeshAuti, your SQL 2022 server us unpatched. I suggest you install the latest CU (currently CU 10). Note TDS 8 and TLS 1.3 are relatively new technologies so interop with legacy ADO (which hasn't been enhanced for 20+ years) may be challenging.

Comment: I now find it even more ironic that you are concerned about using TLS1.3 when you don't even install updates on your instance... Perhaps worry about having more prominent security issues, like injection and unpatched software, first and *then* worry about TLS1.3. It's no good making sure you have the latest and greatest lock on a door, that can't be by passed, if you leave that door unlocked all the time.

Comment: @DanGuzman After applying the latest CU 10 Patch on the SQL server issue is resolved. Now I can perform CRUD Operation with strict option (TLS 1.3) Thank you !!

Comment: That's the first thing you should have done.

Comment: @user692942 I downloaded the latest SQL Express from Microsoft (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=104781) it gives the RTM version only.

Comment: Also this line :
rs("Name")="Rohit"

Aren't you suppose to do it the other way around?

VARNAME = RS("colName")

Comment: @easleyfixed no because they are updating the recordset. Prefer to use a SQL `UPDATE` statement over an `ADODB.Recordset` update though, wouldn’t recommend this approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM) - 16.0.1000.6 (X64) Oct 8 2022
> 05:58:25 Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation Express Edition
> (64-bit) on Windows Server 2022 Standard 10.0  (Build 20348: )
> (Hypervisor)

Your SQL Server 2022 server is unpatched. I suggest you install the latest CU (currently CU 10), especially considering TDS 8 was introduced with SQL Server 2022 and the CUs include fixes to TDS 8 and related encryption.

Be aware that TDS 8 and TLS 1.3 are relatively new technologies so interop with legacy ADO (which hasn't been enhanced for 20+ years) may present additional challenges.