# [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (SECDoClientHandshake()).] SSL security error on windows server 2008

Tags: windows, ssl, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, sqloledb

I have a problem of SQL connection between two servers. One of the servers where the site code is stored is a Windows Server 2008 and my database is on a Windows Server 2003.

Here is a part of my code :

```
Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
ConnStr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=10.0.0.17; Initial Catalog=******;UID=*******;Pwd=********%"
Conn.open ConnStr
```

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server erreur '80004005'
> [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (SECDoClientHandshake()).] SSL security error.

So I saw on the internet people talking about enabling TLS 1.0 on my server and that's what I did on both.

[Here is what I have in both my client and server registers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWH1p.png)

But even after that I still have the same mistake.
Could someone please help me

Answer (score 1):

Someone turned off TLS 1.0 support on your database server - thinking that it would improve security.

The October 2021 update of Windows 10 finally updated the `SQLOLEDB` driver to support TLS 1.2.

Otherwise you'll have to switch the *currently* supported `MSOLEDBSQL` driver. It's the only officially supported SQL Server OLEDB since SQL Server 2012, and it supports TLS 1.2.

Comment: I can't seem to find the relevant release notes of the Windows 11 update you refer to, only the October _2020_ update for Windows _10_ (via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67944011/1026)). Would you care to share the update's URL / version number, please?

Comment: That was a typo; should have said `10`.