# Does SQL-DMO support TLS 1.2?

Tags: sql-server, tls1.2

First of all, I apologize for my lack of technical language.
According to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46011694/does-microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-support-tls-1-2), the other way to connect yes it does by simply changing Provider=SQLOLEDB to Provider=MSOLEDBSQL. I tried and it worked.

But using SQL-DMO fails to connect.

Here's what I use now (Delphi):

```
_SQLServer = interface(_IVSQLDMOStdObject)
.
.
.



oServer      : _SQLServer;


oServer.EnableBcp:=True;
oServer.Connect(F_Server,F_User,F_Password);
```

Thanks a lot!